# SharePoint search 2013 , Do the most visits pages affect their order inside the search result

Tags: 2013, search-results, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-search, ranking

we are working on sharepoint on-premises 2013, and i am not sure how the sharepoint search result will be ordered ? i know that the search results will show the items/pages which have the most relevant search text, but in our case we are working on enterprise wiki site collection, and let say there are 2 wiki pages which have the same text,so will the wiki page which have been most visited have any advantages over the other page? or "how many times the wiki page has been opened by end users" does not have direct impact on its order inside the search result?

Answer (score 0):

Most clicked is a part of the equation.  There's an element of the SharePoint Analytic service running along side search that effects result ranks, but based on Microsoft's own explanation of their rankings: [Overview of search result ranking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/overview-of-search-result-ranking)

- Content
- Metadata
- Web graph data
- File type
- Interaction (Clicks)

are all a part of what makes a search result show up higher.

See here to change ranking of search results: [Changing the ranking of search results](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/changing-the-ranking-of-search-results)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, i already read the link. but when they mentioned "Interaction (Clicks)" are they referring to number of clicks from the search results or general clicks (for example visiting the wiki page from another page OR by manually typing the url OR from external source such as an email)?

Comment: I believe it's referring to search click only.  There's a lot of nuances that are included in that however.  Search Result Web Parts, Content Search Web parts, even List/Library Web parts are all wired into search and effect search results.  A direct link is treated a little differently.  SP Audit Logs sees it as an interaction and it does add to the 'views' on the page/item/document as well as popularity trends.  It will count a view, but since there's less analytical data around the discovery of the item, it won't effect it's ranking as much unless it's viewed a significant amount of times.